# What is the best way to count the number of hits on a folder/Sub Folder/Files in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, elfinder

I want to count the number of times a user accesses a directory, its sub-directories and the files. I am using Asp.Net MVC 5 with ELFinder. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Just look at your raw webserver log files.

Comment: Webserver Log Files? Please explain.

Comment: We can't see how many times a particular directory has been accessed in a month for example.

Comment: Your website runs inside a web-server. Every time a request is made to your server your web-server will append it to a log file. You can use tools like AWStats and WebLogAnalyzer to process these log files to see how often requests are made to particular directories.